# Ansible uri module

Tags: powershell, ansible

I have web url and i have two options enable/disable , Now I am writing ansible playbook to do this which is in Powershell script

My ansible playbook

```
---
- hosts: localhost
  vars:
    applauncher: "xweb"
    jobState: "Disable"
    serverName: "NETBATCH"
    jobName: "Loan1"

  tasks:
    - name: edit app jobs
      uri:
         url: 'http://{{ applauncher }}/Edit/{{ jobState }}?Server={{ serverName }}&JobName={{ jobName }}'
         method: POST
         user: xxxx
         password: xxx
```

I am passing extra vars to disable and enable option , Is it possible to use this option in uri module and which method I should use to select disable/enable option in URL

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you are after, but it took me a while to figure out what you are asking for. Read about vars_prompt playbook keyword: https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_prompts.html